# adding 3 values up to 100 percentage

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to calculate status's percentages based on 3 different numbers of count/
let's say I have 3 statuses 
1) passed
2) Failed
3) Skipped

when there were two cases I managed to work it by setting one calculation by Floor method and another one with Ceil method. They always managed to add two numbers up to 100 perfectly. But now I'm stumped with 3 values. Help would be appreciated.

```
const successRate = Math.floor((this.progressCounts.getStatusCount('Passed') * 100) / this.progressCounts.getTotal()),
        failureRate = Math.ceil((this.progressCounts.getStatusCount('Failed') * 100) / this.progressCounts.getTotal()),
        skippedRate = Math.floor((this.progressCounts.getStatusCount('Skipped') * 100) / this.progressCounts.getTotal());
```

Comment: You're always going to have to adjust - what if they're equally split between the three buckets, for example? Rounding would give you 33 + 33 + 33 == 99.

Comment: yes, either it gives me 99 or 101 based on my total cases.

Comment: But *what would you expect*? Randomly pick one to be 34 instead?

Comment: no of course not that would be problematic if there's only one case available, i was trying to get the largest number out of three using Math.max.apply

Answer (score 1):

That's the problem with percentages and fractions with rounding. The easiest way is probably to `floor` one and `ceil` another, then calculate what to do with the last one depending on the sum so far.

```
const successRate = Math.floor((this.progressCounts.getStatusCount('Passed') * 100) / this.progressCounts.getTotal());
const failureRate = Math.ceil((this.progressCounts.getStatusCount('Failed') * 100) / this.progressCounts.getTotal());
let skippedRate = this.progressCounts.getStatusCount('Skipped');
if (successRate + failureRate + \
         Math.floor(skippedRate * 100)/this.progressCounts.getTotal() == 100) {
    skippedRate = Math.floor(skippedRate * 100)/this.progressCounts.getTotal();
} else {
    skippedRate = Math.ceil(skippedRate * 100)/this.progressCounts.getTotal();
}
```

You might have to fudge it a little, but something along those lines.

Comment: Couldn't you just do `const skippedRate = 100 - (successRate + failureRate)`?

Comment: its on live progress-bar so that wouldn't be feasible.

Answer (score 1):

There is an npm package for this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/percent-round

```js
import percentRound from "percent-round";
percentRound([333, 334, 333], 0);  // [33, 34, 33]
```